# What concepts does math take for granted?

Tags: philosophy, foundations

I suspect there must be some concepts that math takes for granted (there has to be a starting point).

For example, after spending some time thinking about it yesterday, I wondered whether most of math could be produced from the concepts of

1. Negation
2. Identity
3. Cardinality
4. Ordinality
5. Sethood
6. Concepts
7. Universality

It seemed to me that other basic concepts might be derivable from those concepts. For an example of what I mean, below I wrote out how I thought some of those derivations might proceed, roughly.

- A. The universal set - from 6,5,7 - the set of all concepts
- B. Complement - from 1,2,4,5,A - the set of concepts in the universal set and in a subset of it that are not identical.
- C. Difference - from 1,2,4,5 - the set of concepts in two sets that are not identical.
- D. Natural numbers - from 3,5 - the cardinal of sets (e.g. |{ {},{{}} }| )
- E. Less than -  from 1,2,5,D  a subset of a number that is not identical to it.
- G. Intersection - C,2,4,5 - from the set of the concepts that are identical and not of the ones that aren't.
- H. Union - 4,5 - the set of the concepts of two sets.
- I. Addition - 5,3,H,D - the cardinal of a union of two sets.

The question:

*What are the fundamental concepts that we must (or, presently) take for granted when we do math?*

Thank you.

Comment: Rules of logic; induction; "set".

Comment: How do you get the ideas of quantity (cardinal) and order from those?

Comment: For instance "Has the same cardinality" is a relation between sets expressed in terms of the existence of a function with certain properties, a function which is itself a set.

Comment: Right, so "has the same cardinality" relies on identity and cardinality. - Identity is included in the rules of logic, but to my knowledge, cardinality is not (I could be wrong though).

Comment: Hal, recall that all that which is definable in $\sf ZFC$ is definable from the rules of logic and $\in$ (which itself defines "set" along with the axioms of set theory). That includes the term "cardinal".

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you. I only know elementary set-theory. But, how do the ideas of ∈ and in the rules of logic produce the idea of cardinality?

Comment: That is the greatest appeal of set theory, for me, that from just one binary relation and a few axioms, one can do pretty much everything.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I see it that way too. I suspect that we'll learn that the rules of set-theory are somehow tightly analogous to the rules that govern all of our thinking.

Comment: Hal, one can write the formula $F(x)$ stating that $x$ is a set of ordered pairs (choosing a way to encode ordered pairs into sets, e.g. Kuratowski's definition $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ or otherwise) satisfying the condition of a function. Then one write $D(f,x)$ saying that $f$ is a function and $x$ is the domain of $f$, similarly $R(f,y)$ for $y$ is the range of $f$, and $Inj(f)$ for stating that $f$ is an injective function. Then one says that $|A|=|B|$ if $\exists f(D(f,x)\land R(f,y)\land Inj(f))$.

Comment: So that relies on the idea of things being ordered - where does that come from?

Comment: What things? Ordered pair is just a term. Mathematical jargon has a lot of resemblance to natural language, but this resemblance is misleading. Natural transformation do not come from "the nature"; the axiom of choice is not due to free will; and ordered pairs do not entertain a primitive notion of things being ordered. Those are just names, often they represent something, but often enough, this representation is misleading.

Comment: Hm. Okay, so I must misunderstand. But am I justified in believing that when I think of an ordered set, say <a,b> - I add some information to the set containing a,b that I wouldn't have if I expressed them {a,b}?

Comment: True. But ordered pairs are just mathematical objects which obey a certain definition. If you check it carefully, $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ satisfies this definition. So an ordered pair is not some magical new type of object. It's just means that the set $(a,b)$ is as above, and that if $(a,b)=(c,d)$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: Thank you. First, just to be sure, the definition that order pairs obey is derived from some combination of the rules of logic, induction, and the idea of a set? Also, about (a,b), are () equivalent to <>? Regarding your point that (a,b)={{a},{a,b}} provides a definition that makes a=c and b=d from (a,b)=(c,d). I thought about it, but couldn't see how it did it. Would you tell me how it conveys that?

Comment: Persistence: "One and One make Two" will still be true tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think the correct answer to your question is even more parsimonious than the one you' ve given. The whole of math is reducible to standard set theory such as ZFC. ZFC can be expressed in a first-order language whose only non-logical constants are $\in$ and $=$ (in second order logic we can even dispense with identity as a primitive and define it via quantification over sets). So the only primitives needed for doing math are membership and identity (between sets).

Comment: (1) In the modern approach, $=$ is part of the underlying logic; (2) we can dispense of $=$ without leaving first-order logic. Define $a=b\iff\forall x(x\in a\leftrightarrow x\in b)$. Congratulations, you have now a working internal first-order definition of $=$ (assuming the axiom of extensionality).

Comment: Ad (1): Part of the modern approach is something called 'first-order logic without equality', where the symbol = is treated as a non-logical constant and interpreted as some equivalence relation. Models, where = is interpreted as the identity relation can then be singled out to be the _normal_ ones. This approach obviously generalizes the more orthodox one you have in mind.

Comment: To my best of knowledge, the addition of $=$ into the logical symbols is relatively recent.

Comment: (For example, if you look at old papers on set theory, they all explicitly *define* equality via $\in$. Only in newer texts equality appears as part of the logical symbols.)

Comment: Ad(2) Your definition reduces identity to the symbol $\in$, that neither is part of every first-order signature nor is it always interpreted as membership. So, you haven't provided a general first-order definition.

Comment: Your answer explicitly talks about set theory and the language of set theory. I believe that $\in$ is an integral part of that language. So if you want to talk about reducing everything down to sets, yes I have.