# How do the ZFC axioms produce the ideas of order?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

The notion of order (and cardinality, for that matter) seems so basic to me that I can't imagine how it could be derived from anything.

In an answer to a previous question I learned that all the concepts in ZFC can be derived from the rules of logic and the concept of membership.

I'm comfortable with first-order logic and elementary set theory (but not much more than that).

How is the notion of order built up from *just* first-order logical principles and membership? I've just started learning how notions can be built from these principles, so if other notions need to be built in order to build order, it would help me a great deal if you could show how those notions are built.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, we need to know what you mean by "order". The term has lots of uses in math.

In your comment, you explained you had in mind ordered pairs: $(a,b)=(c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$. In ZFC, one usually defines $(a,b)$ to be the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. This is a trick: while $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$  even if $a\neq b$, we have
$$\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\neq\{\{b\},\{b,a\}\}$$ if $a\neq b$.

In fact, if $$\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{\{c\},\{c,d\}\}$$
then $a=c$ and $b=d$. Proof: if $a\neq b$, then the left-hand-side is a set containing two sets, so we must also have $c\neq d$. So each side contains exactly one singleton (a singleton is a set containing a single element). So the singletons must be equal, so $a=c$. So the remaining elements of the two-element sets, $b$ and $d$, must also be equal. However, if $a=b$, then the left-hand-side is just $\{a\}$. (Because $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$.) So $c=d$ and $a,b,c,d$ are all equal.

I'll leave the rest of my original answer as maybe still interesting. Note that this definition of $(a,b)$ is just a trick: using the language I use below, we could say that 
$\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ plays the role of $(a,b)$ in ZFC.

So if you mean the ordering of the natural numbers, then there is one answer; if you mean the ordering of the rationals, or of the reals, those both lead to different answers.

The ZFC axioms formalize certain intuitions about sets. Traditionally in ZFC, we define natural numbers, rationals, etc., as certain kinds of sets. For example, here's a collection of sets that can be used to play the roles of natural numbers:

{}        (the empty set)

{{}}      (a set with 1 element)

{{},{{}}} (a set with 2 elements, namely the sets on the previous two lines)

etc.

So we just *define* 0 to be {}, 1 to be {0}, 2 to be {0,1}, 3 to be {0,1,2} etc.

I said "play the role" above, because no number-theorist actually thinks of 3 as the
set {0,1,2}. The point is that for number theory, we don't really care what 3 *is*, just the relations it has to the other natural numbers. Or in other words, the properties of the system of natural numbers as a whole. These ZFC definitions of the natural numbers enables us to build up a system with all the desired properties.

Zermelo (the Z in ZFC) actually originally used a different bunch of sets for the natural numbers, namely 0={}, 1={{}}, 2={{{}}}, 3={{{{}}}}, etc.; von Neumann used the other collection, which turns out to be technically much more convenient. For one thing, we can *define* $x<y$ (for natural numbers $x$ and $y$) to mean $x\in y$ (since $x$ and $y$ are sets with this approach, and $y$ is the set of all natural numbers less than itself).

We could say that Zermelo and von Neumann cast the same play with a different actors.

That's how it goes for other collections of common mathematical objects, like (say) the reals. Dedekind and Cantor both gave ways of defining real numbers as certain (rather complicated) sets. The sets playing the role of (say) the real numbers $e$ and $\pi$ are very different with Cantor's and Dedekind's definitions. Also, the definition of $x<y$ (in terms of the basic set-theoretic concept of $\in$) is quite different with Cantor's and Dedekind's definitions. Nonetheless, "$e<\pi$" holds with either definition.

Why do we construct the natural numbers, the reals, etc., as certain kinds of sets in ZFC? Why not treat them as primitive objects in their own right, with no internal structure? Well, you could do that. This approach leads to something called "set theory with atoms", i.e., objects that are not sets (the atoms), and then sets built up out of the atoms. While this may seem more natural, it's technically more complicated. You now have two kinds of mathematical objects to worry about: the atoms, and sets. It's just slicker to build up your mathematical universe out of one kind of object: the set.

(Nonetheless, for certain theoretical purposes, set theorists have studied set theory with atoms.)

Comment: That was very helpful. You asked what I meant by order; I had ordered sets in mind. As I understand it, in *<a,b>* - it matters that *a* is on the left and *b* is on the right. I also believe that the definition of an ordered pair is  ( <a,b> = <c,d> ) ↔ ( a=c ∧ b=d ). But how does one extend that definition of order to other expressions without first apprehending that a=c because they occupy the same places in an order? If extending the definition of order depends on one first having an idea of order then the definition doesn't give us the idea so we'd have to derive it some other way, right?

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. That was very interesting. So then, can I regard ordered pairs notated as '<a,b>' as short hand for {{a},{a,b}}?

Comment: Yes. (One cares about this only in the context of axiomatic set theory, but I gather that that's what you're doing.)

Comment: I'm taking a semantics class that is introducing me to some mathematical (not only in set theory) operations. But the class doesn't explain why the operations do what they do. Fair enough - it's not a math course. But it grabs my goat.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I had emailed the philosophy of math prof in my department when I asked this question; I thought you might appreciate his answer:

Comment: "What you mention is the definition of ordered pair (or ordered n-tuple, more generally). An ordered n-tuple is, to put it informally, a set in which "the order of the members matter". So the definition is not meant as a definition of the general notion of order. In fact, I doubt the notion of order can be defined at all, for any definition (say, "a triangle is a figure with three sides") seem to presuppose that one is able to distinguish it from other string of words that contain the same words in a different order (e.g. "a a is with three sides figure triangle")"

Comment: Hmmm. Well, I don't think his point has anything to do with ZFC as a mathematical system. But there is a philosophy stack exchange (and one for cognitive science, and one for linguistics); you could try them for other perspectives.

Comment: I agree with you that it doesn't comment on ZFC as a mathematical system. I thought it was a neat comment about what we had discussed, so I thought it was worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematical notions are translated to definitions (in most cases), which include axioms.

We define cardinality in terms of bijections. We say that $|A|=|B|$ if there exists a function whose domain is $A$ and its range is $B$, and it is injective. And we say that $|A|\leq|B|$ if there exists an injection from $A$ to $B$ (which weakens the above to say that the range of the function is a subset of $B$). Let us work towards that.

In the language of set theory we only have $\in$, but we can *define* as shorthand a lot of other things, $\varnothing,\subseteq,\mathcal P$ and so on. So when we write something like "There is no surjection from a set $A$ onto its power set" we don't have to write this insanely long sentence which will be impossible to understand. (This is somewhat similar to writing software, where you don't just write all the code at once, you add functions and procedures that enrich your language.)

Now. There are some notions which are abstract (like the concept of a function) which we can "implement" in set theory by deciding that a particular object is always interpreted as sets of a certain form. Then we have the prove that indeed this interpretation satisfies the definition of the abstract notion. For example the ordered pair $(a,b)$ is a mathematical object satisfying $(a,b)=(c,d)\iff a=c\land b=d$. In set theory we may choose to define $(a,b)$ as the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. There are other definitions which work, but this one is pretty standard. So now when we write "ordered pair" we mean to say that it is a set which has the above property.

Next, functions. We can define a function as a set of ordered pairs with the property that if $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ are in that set, then $b=c$. This ensures that $f(a)$ is a well-defined object. So now we can write a formula with a free variable $x$, whose content is "*Every element of $x$ is an ordered pair, and if two ordered pairs share the same left-coordinate then they are equal.*"

Then we can write similar formulas saying that $x$ is the domain of a function $f$, and that $y$ is the range of that domain, and that $f$ is an injection, or a bijection.

Finally. We can write a formula $\varphi(A,B)$ "*There exist a function $f$ whose domain is $A$ and its range is $B$ and $f$ is injective*". Simply by composing all the previous things that we expressed. Now given $V$ a universe of $\sf ZFC$ and $A,B\in V$ are two sets, then $V\models\varphi(A,B)$ if it is true (in $V$) that $|A|=|B|$.

Comment: I think OP would be interested to see the Von Neumann ordinals and how they capture the seemingly primitive notion of order inside of ZFC.

Comment: I think that it is a good thing to pace yourself when teaching someone, who seems somewhat confused to begin with. (Admittedly, I don't always follow this advice. But I usually try.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes I agree with that. I added a bit about my background knowledge, which may provide some context.

Comment: @Hal: I don't see the need to change my answer to accommodate the additional information to your question. It seems to me that it describes how we can define $|A|=|B|$ within $\sf ZFC$, and as an exercise, I'll let you think, after you've understood that, how we can define $|A|\leq|B|$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Your answer's great. I made the comment as an aside. But while reading it, I think I found how to make the source of my question more explicit. First, let me say I get (a,b)=(c,d) <=> a=c∧b=d. What I mean to ask is this: Would you not need the concept of order to apply that definition generally? For instance, take the definition: Suppose (p,q)=(r,s) We first ask: what do () mean?, we check the dictionary, it says it means they're ordered and we find the definition  (a,b)=(c,d) <=> a=c∧b=d. Then we infer that p=r, q=s. (cont)

Comment: @Hal: I don't see where "order" comes in the definition of an ordered pair. There's only equality there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But how do we recognize that a and p are analogous? The only way from that definition (and presuming no preexisting relevant knowledge of something else) that p and q are analogous is by their relative order to the other things in the expression. I suspect, most importantly in this case, to their order relative to the other elements. So that is why it seems to me like the definition depends on some preexisting notion of order.

Comment: @AsafKaragila more concisely, I mean: What is the process of thought through which one generalizes that definition to expressions that contain differently represented variables?

Comment: @Hal: Perhaps it is best that before reading this, you overview the basics of logic again. Recall that we use arbitrary and unassigned letters for denoting free variables. If you will feel more comfortable, I can also change all the variables appearing in my answer to the form $x_n$ for a natural number $n$. The axiom of the ordered pair is this $$\forall x_1\forall x_2\forall x_3\forall x_4:(x_1,x_2)=(x_3,x_4)\leftrightarrow x_1=x_3\land x_2=x_4.$$ There is no assumption of "preexisting knowledge of the mysterious $x_0$". Just free variables and then quantifiers.

Comment: And it seems to me that you are trying to cram a very big slice of understanding on how mathematics is defined within set theory into a single answer on MSE. That's just wrong. You should study logic, set theory, and then understand that on your own (and it's easy once you have intermediate understanding of logic and set theory).

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% with you on everything you've said. Let me ask, is it possible but not necessary that X1 and X2 are the same?

Comment: @Hal: I **really** think that you should learn the basics of first-order logic before approaching this question. It's a good question, and it's great that you're spending time thinking about it. But without the tools to understand the answers properly, it seems to me that we're wasting our time.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I get what you're saying. I sincerely appreciate your help, and I understand your answer. But on what basis is (x1,x2)=(x3,x4), x1=x3 x2=4 analogous to (p,q)=(r,s) p=r, q=s (or any other similar expression). The only way is that every variable appears in the same relative order.For example, if I changed the definition to (x2, x1)=(x4, x3), the meaning of the definition would not change, as it depends on what variable is in the *first* and *second* position (ordinal ideas). So it appears to be a circular definition.

Comment: @Hal: I only wrote it again with $x_n$'s because those are clearly variables, as opposed to the $p,q,r,s$ which may perceived as some previously given constants. I still don't fully understand your question. Where are the variables coming from? They live in the language. You can also think about the whole "ordered pair" thing is just an idea. One that I hold in my head. But then I said "OH GOLLY! I CAN WRITE IT IN THE LANGUAGE OF SET THEORY!" and I did. So ordered pairs were never mathematical before, but now they are. And much like I introduced $\mathcal P$ and $\subseteq$, I added $(,)$ too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Easy. You answered a question of mine earlier today (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659498/what-concepts-does-math-take-for-granted?noredirect=1#comment1387997_659498),  which I referenced in this post. That question was, which ideas do we necessarily take for granted - I suggested ordinality was one of them. As you said - 'it's an idea you hold in your head that you can write in set theory'. That statement is close to my point, so let me now rephrase my question: *does set-theory prove order, describe it, or both?*

Comment: @Hal: You wrote cardinality, now you write ordinality. The execution is similar. You need to have an idea about what would make a good definition for order, then express it. The difference is that instead of talking about bijections, you now talk about partial orders, and in particular well-orders. All that is as expressible in set theory as the notion of cardinality is, appearing in my answer above. Now, let me point out that I am **boldly lying to you** when I say that "It was in my head, and now it's here", and math doesn't work like that. [...]

Comment: [...] However I don't think it's possible to write into a single answer the inner working of formalization from an idea to a notion to a mathematical definition to its interpretation in $\sf ZFC$. That's a journey that **you** have to go on your own, with your teachers, books and the occasional questions on MSE (which I will gladly try and answer). When you are done with that journey you will understand how these things work exactly, without someone sitting and writing what can be a very impressive grad level course into a single answer on the internet.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair comments, and again, I sincerely appreciate your answers. And these follow-up questions are intended, in part, to evidence that I think about each of them, that they do contribute to my understanding, and that I appreciate them. That said, one final rephrase so my question is clear on the record. *How do you generalize that definition of order to other expressions without apprehending the order of its constituents?*